# Cakephp Auth problem : Undefined property: User::$alias

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I keep getting this error over a day right now.

I search over and over , but i couldnt get an answer.

Probably i am making sometihing stupid.

Here is my enviroment;

UserController :

class UsersController extends AppController {

```
    var $name = 'Users';
    var $components = array('Email');

    function login() {
    }

    function home() {
        pre('login oldunuz');
    }

    function logout() {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Goodbye!', true));
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    ....
```

}

AppController :
  class AppController extends Controller {

```
    var $components = array('Session','Auth');
    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->loginError = 'You didnt supply valid identification.';
        $this->Auth->authError = 'You are not validated to see this location.';
        $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('register','confirm');
        $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.active' => 1);
    }
    function beforeRender() {
        $this->set('User', $this->Session->read('Auth.User'));
    }
```

}

UserModel: 
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $displayField = 'username';

```
var $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Username field can not be empty..',
        ),
        'u_unique' => array(
            'rule'=>array('isUnique'),
            'message' => 'The username you selected, is being used please choose another one.'
        )
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'message' => 'Please provide a valid email.',
        ),
        'e_unique' => array(
            'rule' => array('isUnique'),
            'message' => 'The email you selected, is being used please choose another one.'
        )
    ),
    ----

  /* if you want i send more of this code */
```

}

I dont how to fix this,
But for helping, cakephp says :

The error portion is :

```
if ($key == null)
{
    $model =& $this->getModel();
    return array($model->alias => $this->Session->read($this->sessionKey));
}
```

if i make `$model->alias = "User"` then it works but where ever another `$model->alias` is used, it explodes same as before,

I hope you have an answer, thanks all,

Comment: Try replacing `$this->set('User', $this->Session->read('Auth.User'));` with `$this->set('User', $this->Auth->user());`

Comment: thanks @joeb , i tried that earlier but again the same error. And even worse, it couldnt set the `$User` , i think it is a loading problem auth couldnt relate itself with the user model at some point of the code.

Comment: In your model, you don't override anything like the __construct() method do you?